# Can i run remotely Windows commands form Mac terminal?

Tags: command-line, terminal, vmware-fusion

Is it possible to run Windows commands (on a VMware BOX installed) from a mac terminal ?

Comment: Actual DOS? Or Windows command line?

Comment: yes windows command line , using vmware fusion

Answer (score 1):

Which variant of VMWare?  The Server variants have many more options than Workstation, which has more options than Fusion.  That said, if you want to work directly from a Terminal window, your best bet is probably to install an `sshd` inside the VM.  Otherwise, your primary options are RDP (`rdesktop`, Remote Desktop Connection, CoRD) or VNC.

Comment: using vmware fusion, i just want send remote calls to start an app on the box example in the command window like: app.exe --args . so what im searching is a method to run from the terminal host machine. Does this make any sense ???

Comment: Installing `sshd` is probably the most familiar way to deal with it, then.  Windows doesn't natively have a remote terminal mechanism, as distinct from a remote GUI.  (Hm, belay that last; I don't know if there's a way to talk to PowerShell. — Looks like "no".  Pity.)

Comment: Windows does have a built-in (well, not installed by default but in the windows components) telnet daemon.  It's really really sucky, but the best windows has without third party software.

Comment: `telnet`.  ${DEITY:-someone} help us.